# Правильный SQL запрос

Tags: sql

Помогите, есть таблица в БД, называется `tasks`, нужно написать запрос так, чтобы выводились только те записи, в которых дата из столбца `termin` была до сегодняшнего дня.

```
$today = getdate(); // получаем сегодняшнюю дату
$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE termin<='$today'"); // датой больше сегодняшной
```

В базе данных столбец `termin` имеет тип `date`

Comment: Я голосую против этого вопроса, т.к. заголовок не информативен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получить текущую дату можно встроенной в MySQL функцией [`CURDATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate), а сравнивать даты можно обычными операторами сравнения. Данный запрос вернет все записи из таблицы `tasks`, где поле `termin` содержит сегодняшнюю или уже прошедшую дату:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `tasks` WHERE `termin` <= CURDATE();");
```

Comment: спасибо, только не `>=` а `<=`, мне нужны записи до сегодняшнего дня

Comment: Ай, точно. Невнимательно прочитал ваш вопрос. Отредактировал ответ.